# How does debugger match my code and pure assemby code?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, debugging, assembly

How I understand Visual Studio debugger use PDB files whiсh provide information on what assembler instructions need to put a breakpoint, for example:

[image]

I also know, that PDB files are generated by Roslyn compiler and provide mapping c# code to IL code, but at runtime, debugger works with assembly code, not CIL.

How does debugger map asm to IL or does it work differently?

Answer (score 0):

The PDB files associate addresses with lines of code and names, and those addresses are dissassembled to coordinate with lines of code. With Visual Studio, you can switch to dissassembler view and breakpoint or step at the assembly level.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand how because PDB files are mapping c# to IL, but in visual studio disassemble I debug assembly code.

Comment: @EvgeniyTerekhin - Visual Studio has an option to compile c# into machine language .exe file, in which case the PDB file refers to addresses of machine language instructions in the .EXE file. There are also tools to work with IL files, [MSDN IL reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) .